# Dataclass Multiple Inheritance (Python)

Tags: python, database, python-dataclasses

I have a special class for trailing logic (it is meant that whenever something is changed with an object this changes are stored into the database.

I decided to create an abstract factory pattern which can produce other classes to make the logic more dynamical.

Here is the BaseTrail class:

```
@dataclass
class BaseTrail(Serializable):

    field_name: Optional[str]
    old_value: Optional[Serializable]
    new_value: Optional[Serializable]
    table_name: str

    # def to_db(self, conn):
    #     return self._insert(conn, "audit_trail", "audit_id")


    @staticmethod
    def record_diffs(
        conn,
        before,
        after,
        **kwargs
    ):
        before_dict = before.to_dict()
        after_dict = after.to_dict()
        for field, before_value in before_dict.items():
            after_value = after_dict.get(field)
            if str(before_value) != str(after_value):
                record = BaseTrail(
                    field_name=field,
                    old_value=before_value,
                    new_value=after_dict,
                    **kwargs
                )
                record.to_db(conn)
```

Basically it takes the old fields --> checks everytime if something has changed and records it to the database ( The Serializable class from which it is inherited is used for  creating a json from the object.

The following class has to trail each change to the order (Attaching the code below)

```
@dataclass
class OrdersTrail(BaseTrail, Serializable):
    customer_id: int
    order_id: int
    updated_order_status: Optional[str]
    created_by: Optional[int]
    created_on: Optional[datetime]
    current_all_time_owed: Decimal
    action: Optional[str]
    table_name: str  # TODO make a property
    order_trail_id: Optional[int] = None

    def to_db(self, conn: connection) -> None:
        self._insert(conn, 'order_trail', 'order_trail_id')

    @staticmethod
    def record_diffs(
            conn,
            old_value,
            new_value,
            **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        before_dict = old_value.to_dict()      # serializing values before changes
        after_dict = new_value.to_dict()    # serializing changed values

        for field, before_value in before_dict.items():
            after_value = after_dict.get(field)
            if str(before_value) != str(after_value):
                print(kwargs)
                OrdersTrail(
                    table_name="order_trail",
                    **kwargs
                ).to_db(conn)
```

And when I create an object of this class writing other

```
 OrdersTrail.record_diffs(
            conn=connection,
            current_user=current_user,
            customer_id=order.customer_id,
            order_id=order.order_id,
            updated_order_status=order.order_status,
            old_value=customer_order,
            new_value=order,
            action=update_order.__name__,
            current_all_time_owed=totals.all_time_owed
        )
```

I receive this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 10 required positional arguments: 'field_name', 'old_value', 'new_value', 'customer_id', 'order_id', 'updated_order_status', 'created_by', 'created_on', 'current_all_time_owed', and 'action'
```

Can someone explain please, why it is happening and how to fix this problem, thank you so much!